# How to parse a string and convert date values into datetime values in Java

Tags: java, string, datetime, data-conversion

I have a `String` that contains an expression like this:

```
final String expression = "id = 123 AND openDate < 2023-01-01 AND closeDate = 2024-01-01";
```

As `openDate` and `closeDate` are deprecated and got replaced by `openDateTime` and `closeDateTime`, I need to fix the expression before executing it like this:

```
final String newExpression = expression
        .replaceAll("\\bopenDate\\b", "openDateTime")
        .replaceAll("\\bcloseDate\\b", "closeDateTime");
```

The statement above results in the following expression:

```
"id = 123 AND openDateTime < 2023-01-01 AND closeDateTime > 2024-01-01"
```

The problem is that I also need to convert the actual date values into datetime so that the final expression is like this:

```
"id = 123 AND openDateTime < 2023-01-01 00:00 AND closeDateTime = 2024-01-01 00:00"
```

How do I to get the actual dates **next** to  `openDate` and `closeDate` so that I can convert them into datetime values?

Comment: If your dates are well formated may be a you could add `.replaceAll("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}", "$0 00:00");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
    final String newExpression = expression.replaceAll(
            "\\s(openDate|closeDate)\\s*([<>]=?|=)\\s*(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})", 
            " $1Time $2 $3 00:00");
```